# How does the offset parameter works in the function abbreviate(String str,int offset,int maxWidth), in package org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

Tags: java, apache, apache-stringutils

I am presently working with the apache commons lang package, StringUtils class.
I found there are two abbreviation methods: `abbreviate(String str,int maxwidth)` and `abbreviate(String str,int offset,int maxwidth)` it is absolutely ok with the first one. But when come to the second one it is little bit confusing and I really need the clarification.
I saw two cases of the `abbreviate(String str,int offset,int maxwidth)` function. those are:-

```
abbreviate("abcdefghijklmno",1,10)
```

returns "abcdefg...", and the second:

```
abbreviate("abcdefghijklmno",4,10)
```

also returns "abcdefg...".

After seeing this I am really in confution how exactly the offset parameter works??

Comment: Please give a full explanation of the `StringUtils.abbreviate(String str,int ofset,int maxwidth)` method.

Comment: more details on the StringUtils class and it's methods are now availabe on: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/lang3/stringutils/org-apache-commons-lang3-stringutils-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JavaDoc of the method:

> allows you to specify a "left edge" offset. Note that this left edge
>   is not necessarily going to be the leftmost character in the result,
>   or the first character following the ellipses, but it will appear
>   somewhere in the result.

In the code of the method you find

```
if (offset <= 4) {
   return str.substring(0, maxWidth - 3) + "...";
}
```

You can read the code here: http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java.htm

So both examples you give should return `"abcdefg..."`. Are you sure you got `"abcdefgh"` ?

Comment: sorry that was my mistakes. It will be "abcdefg...".

Comment: But the answer you gave is already known to me I need a proper clarification how it exactly does it.